# Expensive to set UILabel.attributedText to the same value?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a view controller within my app that I use for debugging purposes to display some of the internals of the app (only for local xcode builds, the app store version doesn't have this controller).

In this controller, I have a label which I want to reflect the state of an internal component (specifically, I want it to display whether that component is enabled or disabled).

My questions:

**#1: Is it expensive to set the `.attributedText` property of a UILabel to the same value as it was before, or should I cache the old value and only set the property when it changes?**

**#2: What about the `.text` (non-attributed) property?**

I'm currently using the following code:

```
// Schedule timer to update the control panel. (This is debug-only, so not worth
// the complexity of making this event-based)
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5,
                 repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        // Stop timer if we've been dealloced or are no longer being presented
        guard let strongSelf = self,
              strongSelf.isBeingPresented else
        {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }

        // "Something Enabled / Disabled" label
        let somethingIsEnabled = strongSelf.someDepenency.isEnabled
        let somethingEnabledString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Something ")

        somethingEnabledString.append(NSAttributedString(string: isEnabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled",
                                                         attributes: isEnabled ? nil : [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(xtHardcodedHexValue: "0xCD0408")]))
        strongSelf.somethingEnabledLabel?.attributedText = somethingEnabledString

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a performance issue? There doesn't seem to be a real point to this question.

Comment: Well, some members on my team are concerned about (during CR). You're right though, it's mostly a curiosity and to enhance my understanding of UIKit.

What about if the label had to update 60x per second? What if we had 100s of labels with `attributedText`?

Comment: You test. You measure performance. Only if you actually have a problem do you attempt to do anything about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I share some numbers, I'd *highly recommend* to not perform such premature optimizations. Consider the following code:

```
private func getAttributedString() -> NSMutableAttributedString{
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Something ")
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Enabled",
                                                     attributes:  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(rgb: 0xCD0408)]))
    return attributedString
}

//overwrites attributed text 100000 times
@IBAction func overwriteAttributedText(_ sender: Any) {
    let timeBeforeAction = Date.init()
    print ("Time taken to overwrite attributed text is ")
    for _ in 1 ... 100000{
        label.attributedText = getAttributedString()
    }
    let timeAfterAction = Date.init()
    let timeTaken = timeAfterAction.timeIntervalSince(timeBeforeAction)
    print(timeTaken)
}

//overwrites attributed text 100 times
@IBAction func cacheAttributedText(_ sender: Any) {
    let timeBeforeAction = Date.init()
    print ("Time taken to selectively overwrite attributed text is ")
    for i in 1 ... 100000{
        if i % 1000 == 0 {
            label.attributedText = getAttributedString()
        }
    }
    let timeAfterAction = Date.init()
    let timeTaken = timeAfterAction.timeIntervalSince(timeBeforeAction)
    print(timeTaken)
}

//overwrites text 100000 times
@IBAction func overWriteText(_ sender: Any) {
    let defaultText = "Hello World"
    let timeBeforeAction = Date.init()
    print ("Time taken to overwrite text is ")
    for _ in 1 ... 100000{
        label.text = defaultText
    }
    let timeAfterAction = Date.init()
    let timeTaken = timeAfterAction.timeIntervalSince(timeBeforeAction)
    print(timeTaken)
}
```

Here are the results:

```
Time taken to overwrite attributed text is 0.597925961017609
Time taken to selectively overwrite attributed text is 0.004891037940979
Time taken to overwrite text is 0.0462920069694519
```

The results speak for themselves, but I leave it you if such optimizations are even needed.

Comment: Thanks for the numbers. As you said, definitely not worth premature optimization, but quite interesting to see the performance difference.

Answer (score 5):

While 7to4 is correct in regards to premature optimizations, the demo code he's using is misleading.  The `.attributedText` setter itself is actually faster than setting `.text`; creating the attributed string is the bottleneck.  Here's a modified version of his code that includes a method where the attributed string is pre-cached:

```
private func getAttributedString() -> NSMutableAttributedString{
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Something ")
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Enabled",
                                               attributes:  [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]))
    return attributedString
}

//overwrites attributed text 100000 times
@IBAction func overwriteAttributedText(_ sender: Any) {
    let timeBeforeAction = Date.init()
    print ("Time taken to overwrite attributed text is ")
    for _ in 1 ... 100000{
        label.attributedText = getAttributedString()
    }
    let timeAfterAction = Date.init()
    let timeTaken = timeAfterAction.timeIntervalSince(timeBeforeAction)
    print(timeTaken)
}

//overwrites attributed text 100000 times with a cached string
@IBAction func overwriteAttributedTextWithCachedString(_ sender: Any) {
    let timeBeforeAction = Date.init()
    let attributedString = getAttributedString()
    print ("Time taken to overwrite attributed text with cached string is ")
    for _ in 1 ... 100000{
        label.attributedText = attributedString
    }
    let timeAfterAction = Date.init()
    let timeTaken = timeAfterAction.timeIntervalSince(timeBeforeAction)
    print(timeTaken)
}

//overwrites text 100000 times
@IBAction func overWriteText(_ sender: Any) {
    let defaultText = "Hello World"
    let timeBeforeAction = Date.init()
    print ("Time taken to overwrite text is ")
    for _ in 1 ... 100000{
        label.text = defaultText
    }
    let timeAfterAction = Date.init()
    let timeTaken = timeAfterAction.timeIntervalSince(timeBeforeAction)
    print(timeTaken)
}
```

Results:

```
Time taken to overwrite attributed text is 
0.509455919265747
Time taken to overwrite attributed text with cached string is 
0.0451710224151611
Time taken to overwrite text is 
0.0634149312973022
```

On average, the `.attributedText` setter itself is about 30~40% faster than the `.text` setter.  That said, take note that it probably takes *a lot* of labels before this actually becomes a bottleneck.  Also remember that (if by some crazy circumstance) this is your bottleneck, this optimization is only effective if the attributed string is pre-allocated ahead of time.